# Inequalities with limits

Tags: limits, inequality, continuity

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Suppose that $f(x) \geq 4\space\space\forall \space x\in [0,1)$

This **implies** that $$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}f(x)\geq 4$$

However, is the converse statement of this is also true? that is, given the limit and that the function is continuous, can we conclude the inequality:

$$f(x) \geq 4 \space\forall\space x \in \space \mathbb{K}$$

where $\mathbb{K}$ is a right punctured neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: what about $f(x) = 4x$?

Comment: Wouldn't $f(x) = 4-x^2$ work as a counterexample? The limit is $4$, but that's the highest value achieved.

Comment: What about $f(x)=4-4x$.

Comment: "However, is the converse statement of this is also true?" Of course not.  just because a function has a limit that is more than $4$ doesn't mean $f(x)$ must be more than $4$ everywhere else in an interval.  Just take a function with $f(\frac 12) = 0$ and but quickly grows to $4$ and beyond as it goes to $0$.  [$f(x) = 4x$ and $f(x)=4-x^2$ or $f(x)=4-4x$ are excellent counter examples by commenters above but there are gazillions of other counterexamples.]

Comment: Counter example:  $f(x) = 5\cos(500\pi\cdot x)$.  That function will just oscillate between $-5$ and $5$ five hundred times in the interval before stopping and $f(0)=5> 4$.

Answer (score 1):

The converse of the statement would be If $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) \ge 4$ then $f(x) \ge 4$ for all $x$ in $[0,1)$.  (Which is obviously false)

The converse is *not* that $f(x) \ge 4$ for all $x$ is *some* $\mathbb K$ where $\mathbb K = [0,\delta)$ for some $\delta$. (which is true if $\lim f(x) > 4$ but not if $\lim f(x) = 4$.)

Your statement is not true if you consider a function where $f(0) = 4$ and $f(x) < 4$ for all $x > 0$>

However it is true that if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=c > 4$ (*strictly* greater) than there exists a $\delta$ so that $f(x) > 4$ for all $x \in [0, \delta)$.  This follows directly from the definition of continuity.  Let $\epsilon = c - 4$ then there exists a $\delta$ so that if $x\in [0,\delta)$ then $|f(x) - c| < \epsilon$ and therefore $f(x) < c-\epsilon = 4$.